# Pandas df.iterrows() method to access a set number of rows:

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am looping through a dataframe using df.iterrows(). Instead of looping through all the rows, I would like to set the number of rows accessed each time. First I would like to access the first two rows, then it will be the third to the sixth row and then the remaining. Is there a way to loop through the rows?

Here is what I have:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

 df['key1'] = 0
 df.key1.iloc[0:3] = 1
 df.key1.iloc[3:7] = 2
 df.key1.iloc[7:] = 3

 df_grouped = df.groupby('key1')

 for group_name, group_value in df_grouped:
     fig, axes = plt.subplots(rows, 1, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize= (15, 20))
     for i,r in group_value.iterrows():
         rows, columns = group_value.shape
         r = r[0:columns-1]
         r.plot(kind='bar', fill=False, log=False)
```

Comment: Can you show us what must be the value(s) of `i` at each iteration? Would it be a scalar or a list of indices?

Comment: 'i' is the row number and helps get the data in each row using df.iloc[I,1:]. So, at each instance in the loop it will be a scalar. Thanks for your help. Not sure if I have answered your question well but I hope this makes sense.

Comment: So, how do you want to use those group of indices as you mentioned : `[0,1]`, then `[2,3,4,5]` and then rest?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: I mean those `[0,1]`, then `[2,3,4,5]` can't be `i` because as you said `i` has to be a scalar. So, do you want two levels of looping, one that selects one of those three groups and next loop select `i ` from the elements of the selected group?

Comment: Yes, the [0,1], [2,3,4,5] and [7 and above] are not the 'i's but the set/list I would like to access each time to do the plotting. This way I am not plotting the entire dataset all at once but instead slicing them as one set at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a column according your condition, then do a group by over that column and iterated over the grouped data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

df['key1'] = 0
df.key1.iloc[1:3] = 1
df.key1.iloc[3:7] = 2
df.key1.iloc[7:] = 3

df_grouped = df.groupby('key1')

for group_name, group_value in df_grouped:
    for i,r in group_value.iterrows():
        print i, max(r[:-1])
    print '-' * 80
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the above code and here is what get..
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. It does not slice the data frame actually.

Comment: This is just a example, based on your condition create a column like that. Pls note it is a warning only, you should check the value of df.key1

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have progress. However, I am not able to create the plot where each subplot is plotted. In a group of three in a set, I have only one of the plots plotted where there is no data for the remaining two plots in a group. it looks like the 'r' value does not pass to 'r.plot'. Any input on why it does not pass to all the subplots? Please see edit in my original question above.